# Creating a Mesh from MRTK Hand joints

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, hololens

I have an application for Hololens 2 where i need to show other participants' hands.
I got the networking part, but i now have a set of 25 HandJoint positions per hand. I would like to visualize the hand as a mesh in the same style as the one the MRTK provides for the users own hand.
I could use any hints about where to look next.

Visualized joints of the MRTK Hand

[image: 1]

MRTK Hand Mesh (incl. Joints)

[image: 2]

Comment: Are you looking for the visual assets that MRTK provides? If it is the case you may find it at [MixedReality Toolkits Obejct/Component] -> [Input] -> [Articulated Hand Tracking], where all resources are listed.

Comment: @SethDU-MSFT Thank you for the answer. I sadly cant find the package you are referring to. I only have the Examples, Extensions, Foundation, PlaneFinding, StandardAssets and Tools Packages.
I would have assumed the asset to be in the Standard Assets Package, but there i cant find it.

Comment: Hi Andreas,  maybe this helps with the resources for location?   https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/main/Assets/MRTK/SDK/StandardAssets/Prefabs

Comment: Thank you very much. I will see if i can do sth with those assets!

Comment: I will summarize and convert the above comments to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the visual assets/prefabs that MRTK provides, you may find it at [Unity MixedReality Toolkits Obejct/Component] -> [Input] -> [Articulated Hand Tracking] in MRTK 2.8+.

You may also find those resources at https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/main/Assets/MRTK/SDK/StandardAssets/Prefabs